# Having problem clicking Instagram prompt buttons using selenium

Tags: selenium-webdriver, instagram

After logging in to my instagram account, instagram shows two prompts:

the first asking to save login details & the next asking to turn on notifications.

My code should press the 'Not now' button. But it is not working.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException
import configparser

config = configparser.ConfigParser()
config.read("config.ini")
USERNAME = config["Instagram"]["username"]
PASSWORD = config["Instagram"]["password"]

chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
chrome_options.add_experimental_option("detach", True)

driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=chrome_options)


URL =  "https://www.instagram.com/accounts/login/"


driver.get(URL)

# Locate username and password fields
username_field = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="loginForm"]/div/div[1]/div/label/input')))
password_field = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="loginForm"]/div/div[2]/div/label/input')))

# Enter username and password
username_field.send_keys(USERNAME)
password_field.send_keys(PASSWORD)
password_field.send_keys(Keys.ENTER)

# Close pop-ups, handling potential delays and exceptions
try:
    # WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//button[contains(text(), 'Not Now')]"))).click()
    btn1 = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//button[contains(text(), 'Not Now')]")
    btn1.click()
except TimeoutException:
    print("'Save login info' prompt not found.")

try:
    # WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//button[contains(text(), 'Not now')]"))).click()
    btn2 = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//button[contains(text(), 'Not now')]")
    btn2.click()
except TimeoutException:
    print("'Turn on Notifications' prompt not found.")
```

I have tried getting the actual xpath of the buttons, but it did not work either.

Comment: Did u get any errors ? if yes, can u provide the logs of your run